# Декодирование JSON через библиотеку

Tags: actionscript-3, json, flash

Проблема возникла при декодировании полученный информации в Adobe Flash.

Импортировал JSON: "import com.adobe.serialization.json.*;".

Попытался в функции декодировать JSON строку: "var msg:Object = JSON.decode("JSON_строка");".

В ответ получаю ошибку: "1061: Обращение к возможно неопределенному методу decode через ссылку статического типа Class.".

Собственно не понимаю, почему он говорит, что decode не присутствует в JSON классе, если он там есть. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скачал - https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

Установил - import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

```
var msg:Object = JSON.decode("JSON_строка");
```

Действительно выдал ошибку.

Записал так:

```
var msg:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode("JSON_строка");
```

Заработало.